# Python code for sentiment analysis

Tags: python

Initially nltk produced an error,

> import nltk
>
> ImportError: No module named nltk

which I resolved by installing `nltk`. Now it produces the below code as error

> self.nltk_splitter = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'data'

What is the module that should be added for data?

Answer (score 3):

```
import nltk.data
```

in short. Then you have the module available.